Issue with out.width not affecting image size in officedown::rdocx_document
I am trying to generate a Word document with R using the officedown::rdocx_document output format. When I use the standard output: word_document option, I can easily control the size of images in the output by setting different values for the out.width parameter in my RMarkdown document. However, when I switch to officedown::rdocx_document, the images are not resizing as expected. No matter what value I set for out.width, the image size remains unchanged.
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
Using output: word_document option:
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown)
library(officer)
```

### out.width='10%'

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='10%'}
boxplot(1:8)
```

### out.width='90%'

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='90%'}
boxplot(1:8)
```


Using officedown::rdocx_document option:
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown)
library(officer)
```

### out.width='10%'

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='10%'}
boxplot(1:8)
```

### out.width='90%'

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='90%'}
boxplot(1:8)
```



I read somewhere that out.width and out.height does not work with Word documents (whereas the fig. prefixed arguments do work with Word documents). I haven't found where I've read that...yet. I'll keep looking and if I find it, I'll get back to you.
